# Does the Gale-Shapley algorithm provide just one allocation?

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, mechanism-design, algorithms

I know that in a marriage problem for example, you may have more than one stable allocations but I think that the Gale-Shapley algorithm just provide only one.

Comment: In the usual setting with strict preferences,  there is one for each proposing side. These two allocations coincide if and only if there is a unique stable matching.